# Show specific comments from adapter in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on the comment session on an android app using Model with FirestoreRecyclerAdapter. The comment stores on Firestore and I use Model and adapter to show comments text which store in text_review. Here is my model:

```
public class Comment {
    float fireness_rating;
    String post_id;
    String review_time;
    String receiver_id;
    String text_review;


    public Comment(){
        //empty const needed.
    }

    Comment(float fireness_rating, String post_id, String review_time, String receiver_id, String text_review){
        this.fireness_rating=fireness_rating;
        this.post_id=post_id;
        this.review_time=review_time;
        this.receiver_id=receiver_id;
        this.text_review=text_review;

    }

    public float getFireness_rating() {
        return fireness_rating;
    }

    public String getPost_id() {
        return post_id;
    }

    public String getReview_time() {
        return review_time;
    }

    public String getReceiver_id() {
        return receiver_id;
    }

    public String getText_review() {
        return text_review;
    }
}
```

The model contains five elements, but I am mainly focusing on text_review. If the user has text comments inside, the text_review will contain the text the users type and store on firestore. This is the firestore structure after the user comments with text_review.

[image]

As I mentioned, if there are no actual text comment insides the text_review should be empty. I've built an adapter to recursive all the list of comments to present on my activity pages. Here is my adapter.

```
public class Comment_Adapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Comment, Comment_Adapter.CommentHolder> {

    public Comment_Adapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Comment> options){
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final CommentHolder holder, int i, @NonNull Comment model) {

        final String commented_userid = model.getReceiver_id();
        Log.d("comment_adapter_debug", commented_userid);

        //shown only if the use has comment which in text_review
        Query q = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("user_reviews").document(commented_userid).collection("fairness").whereGreaterThan("text_review", "");
        q.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                Log.d("comment_adapter_debug", "has comment inside x");

                //retrieve info, you can ignore this part.               FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("users").document(commented_userid).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                            String first_name = document.get("first_name").toString();
                            String last_name = document.get("last_name").toString();
                            String username = document.get("username").toString();
                            Log.d("comment_adapter_debug", first_name + " " + last_name + ": w/ username= " + username);

                            holder.CommentedFullName.setText(first_name + " " + last_name);
                            holder.CommentedUser.setText("@" + username);
                        } else {
                            Log.d("comment_adapter_debug", "no comment yet for this user.");
                        }

                    }
                });
            }

        });
        String oldstring = model.getReview_time();
        Date dt = new Date(oldstring);
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy").format(dt);
        holder.CommentedDate.setText(timeStamp);
        holder.Comment.setText(model.getText_review());

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CommentHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_comment, parent, false);
        return new CommentHolder(v);
    }

    class CommentHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private ImageView CommentedIcon;
        private TextView CommentedFullName;
        private TextView CommentedUser;
        private TextView CommentedDate;
        private TextView Comment;

        public CommentHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            CommentedIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.commented_icon);
            CommentedFullName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.commented_fullname);
            CommentedUser = itemView.findViewById(R.id.commented_user);
            CommentedDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.commented_date);
            Comment = itemView.findViewById(R.id.commented);
        }
    }

}
```

and this is the image
[image]

All I want is only show there are actual comment ("aaa" from the pic), and the red circle should not be shown since there is no comment exist ("text_review" == ""). My approach is to make a query whereGreaterThan("text_review", "") which means to check if text_review contains texts. If so, show the list, otherwise, skip the whole list. I know it is a little bit long but any help would appreciate.

Comment: Hi @zionnoizy could you please edit your question and add the structure/scheme of your Collections? This way, it will be easier to check how the documents are being organized and stored on it.

Comment: I added more detail for the question, thank you for remind.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for editing your question!

Considering your database, I would give it a try using the below code sample, to verify if the `text_review` has value for the correctly printing of it.

```
...
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
        String first_name = document.get("first_name").toString();
        String last_name = document.get("last_name").toString();
        String username = document.get("username").toString();
        if (document.exists()) {
            if (document.get("text_review") != null) {
                Log.d("comment_adapter_debug", first_name + " " + last_name + ": w/ username= " + username);
                holder.CommentedFullName.setText(first_name + " " + last_name);
                holder.CommentedUser.setText("@" + username);
            } else {
                Log.d("comment_adapter_debug", "no comment yet for this user.");
            }
        }
    }
}
...
```

**While this code is untested**, I believe it should help you as a starting point. As you can check on it, you will be checking in the `document.get("text_review")` part, if the value is `null` or not and based on it, print the information as you want. In case it's not, it will print that the user doesn't have a comment yet - or you can change that last `Log.d` if you prefer.

Let me know if the information helped you!